# SDL2 mouse motion event keeps occurring

Tags: input, sdl, game-loop, sdl2

The code I'm using is like so:

```
SDL_Event e;
SDL_PollEvent(&e);
switch (e.type)
{
    case SDL_MOUSEMOTION:
    {
        YCam += e.motion.yrel; 
    }
    break;
}
```

When I run the program, nothing happens, however, once I first move the mouse, the `SDL_MOUSEMOTION` event keeps firing and the mouse keeps moving. This occurs even when I've stopped moving my mouse. Pressing any key including mouse keys stops the movement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not checking the return value of [`SDL_PollEvent`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PollEvent) to see if there's a new event, which means that regardless of whether there *is* an event to handle, you're trying to handle one. In practice, this means that you're constantly handling the last event, even if it's no longer occurring. Try this:

```
SDL_Event e;
if (SDL_PollEvent(&e)) {
    switch (e.type)
    {
        case SDL_MOUSEMOTION:
        {
            YCam += e.motion.yrel; 
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This fixed the issue I highlighted in the question. One thing I'd like to add is that using if(SDL_PollEvent(&e)) causes the movement to lag behind when moving the mouse fast. Using while(SDL_PollEvent(&e)) seems to fix this. Any idea why?

Comment: @LASERBEARASSAULTUNIT `while` is a tighter loop; it handles all of the events before doing the rest of the stuff in that loop (which probably involves moving the camera and re-rendering).